# Achievement system for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, achievements

I currently have WordPress tube website running on detube theme.

I want to put a level / achievement sytem on my website, which should work for example like this: If the user watches 100 minutes of videos he reaches to level 2 and gets a certain reward associated with the level. For any other level, the user has to complete some other task.

Is it possible? Don't laugh if I asked a foolish question.

Comment: I don't think your question is foolish, but maybe off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you want to ask more questions on Stack Overflow, you might consider asking them on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com, which would help bringing your questions to the right audience.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a achievements system like that?
https://wordpress.org/plugins/achievements/